# scp between 2 remote hosts - without password

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I use paramiko module and I can simply put and get files to and from remote host. Is there the way I can copy the file between 2 remote hosts? 
I have pem file on my local host so I can establish ssh to both hosts. Is there the way I can do it without (if possible) additional configuration on remote hosts - using SSH key and without passwords?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file (path_to_priv_key_file)
ssh.connect(host, username = username,  key_filename=path_to_priv_key_file)
```

I have connection to remote host, but when I try

```
cmd = "scp –v /usr/local/1.py user1@hos1:/usr/local"
ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Are you able to SSH from the first host to the next without passwords already?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the correct private key on the computer you are trying to scp from

Comment: but I can execute other commands on those hosts

Comment: 2mariusnn I am able to connect from my local host to host1 or host2 without password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would like to have a password less connection between two machines.
It is dangerous unless you can assure that no one else has access to the client machine.

Take a look here how to create the password less connection I have described thee years ago in my blog.
It will solve scp issue as well.

http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.com/2009/10/ssh-and-scp-without-being-asked-for.html

Answer (score 3):

Hey Francheska,

The following python pseudo code may help you... Replace dest_server, source_file, dest_file with your appropriate... It is tested and working one...

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('dest_server-IP', username='user', password='passwd')

print "connected successfully!"

sftp = ssh.open_sftp() 
sftp.put('source_file', 'dest_file_path_in_dest_server') 
sftp.close() 
print "copied successfully!"
```

Cheers,

Sumanth

Answer (score 0):

try this to copy dirs and nested subdirs from local to remote:

```
cmd = "sshpass -p {} scp -r {}/* root@{}://{}".format(
    remote_root_pass, 
    local_path, 
    remote_ip, 
    remote_path)
os.system(cmd)
```

don't forget to import os, You may check the exitcode returned (0 for success)

Also you might need to "yum install sshpass"

And change /etc/ssh/ssh_config StrictHostKeyChecking ask to: StrictHostKeyChecking no